# Junit5 multidimensional file source

Tags: java, junit5

I need to write a test that requires setup and actual test data.
Simplified code will be like:

```
//given config
purchase_configs.add(pc1);
purchase_configs.add(pc2);

sales_configs.add(sc1);
sales_configs.add(sc2);

// given data
input_value = ....
//given expected output
expected_value = ....

//when
result = calculate(purchase_configs, sales_configs, input_value)

//then
assertEquals(expected_value, result)
```

In fact configs and input values are quite complex, so I want to externalise them to file/files e.g. using `@CSVFileValue`
Apart of the params the test logic is the same.

The issue is that number of purchase and sales configs may vary. Sometimes it's pc1, pc2, sometimes only pc1, sometimes, none, sometimes more. Same for sales.

I know, that I can write multiple test - one per number of configs, but seems to be ugly.
I know, that I can use `@MethodSource` and generate variable list of params, but then I need to write all the code for parsing CSV/JSON or whatever file or have a lot of Java code to create objects manually, also, if possible I'd like to externalize only important/meaningful params, all the rest can use some default/calculated not to decrease the readability.

Is there any clever way to use junit `@ParametrizedTest` to achieve the goal which is have one test method with params and, if possible do not need to create readers and parsers of files on myown?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do

```java
@Test
void testScenario1() {
   assertCalculation(
      "input1.json",
      List.of("purchaseConfig1.json", "purchaseConfig2.json"),
      List.of("salesConfig1.json", "salesConfig2.json"),
      "expected1.json"
   );
}

@Test
void testScenario2() {
   assertCalculation(
      "input2.json",
      List.of("purchaseConfig3.json", "purchaseConfig4.json"),
      List.of("salesConfig3.json", "salesConfig4.json"),
      "expected2.json"
   );
}

private void assertCalculation(
   String inputPath, 
   List<String> purchaseConfigPaths, 
   List<String> salesConfigPaths, 
   String expectedPath
) {
   Input input = readValue(inputPath, Input.class);
   List<PurchaseConfig> purchaseConfigs = purchaseConfigPaths.stream()
      .map(pc -> readObject(pc, PurchaseConfig.class)
      .collect(toList());
   List<SalesConfig> salesConfigs.stream()
      .map(sc -> readObject(sc, SalesConfig.class)
      .collect(toList();
   Result result = someService.calculate(purchaseConfigs, salesConfigs, input);
   String resultJson = objectMapper.writeValueToString(result);
   assertThat(resultJson).isEqualTo(readString(expectedPath));
}

private <T> T readObject(String path, Class<T> type) { ... }

private String readString(String path) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### @MethodSource

Use `@ParameterizedTest` with a method source that provides arguments via `@MethodSource` and a name of such the method. Here you go and feel free to edit the object types to match your expectations:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arguments")
public void test_calculate(List<String> pc, List<String> sc, String input_value, String expected_value) {
    purchase_configs.addAll(pc); // assuming it's a List
    sales_configs.addAll(sc); // assuming it's a List

    result = calculate(purchase_configs, sales_configs, input_value);

    assertEquals(expected_value, result);
}

private static Stream<Arguments> arguments() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(
                    List.of("pc1", "pc2", "pc3"),
                    List.of("sc1", "sc2", "sc3"),
                    "input1",
                    "outpu1"),
            Arguments.of(
                    List.of(), // sometimes none
                    List.of("sc1", "sc2", "sc3"),
                    "input2",
                    "outpu2"),
            Arguments.of(
                    List.of("pc1", "pc2", "pc3"),
                    List.of(), // sometimes none
                    "input3",
                    "outpu3")
    );
}
```

---

#### @CsfFileSouce

In case you have inputs in a file, you can use `@CsfFileSouce` loading a CSV file ([source](https://reflectoring.io/tutorial-junit5-parameterized-tests)):

```java
@CsvFileSource(
    files = "src/test/resources/test_calculate.csv", 
    numLinesToSkip = 1)
```

You might want to use `ArgumentsAggregator` and `ArgumentsAccessor` if you want to map the file content into objects.

---

#### Custom ParameterResolver

In case you want to define an own argument source, for example from a non-CSV file, you have to implement own `ParameterResolver` and instroduce a custom annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ExtendWith(FileResourceParameterResolver.class)
@interface FileResource {

    String value();
}
```

```java
public class FileResourceParameterResolver implements ParameterResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return parameterContext.isAnnotated(FileResource.class) && parameterContext.getParameter().getType().equals(String.class)
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        var location = parameterContext
                .findAnnotation(FileResource.class)
                .map(FileResource::value)
                .orElseThrow();
        try (var stream = FileResourceParameterResolver.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(location)) {
            if (stream != null) {
                return new String(stream.readAllBytes(), UTF_8);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is simple, just navigate to the resource in the `resources` location in the classpath:

```
@Test
public void foo(@StringResource("folder/bla.json") String json) {) {
    // deserialize JSON string into object and do some testing...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer - this is one of options I considered, but also, as mentioned in the question - considered suboptimal, cause I wanted to put config into the file(s).

Comment: Use `@CsvFileSource`, see my edit.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but still CSV is a flat file, so it is not so easy to put there lists of objects, anyway thanks for trying to help

Comment: Yes, correct, for that reason, you need to maintain a flat structure in the CSV file and use `ArgumentsAggregator` and `ArgumentsAccessor` to create an Object for it. However, if you are fine with for example JSON format, see my edited answer.